# Why is batch variable not immediately set?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to query a user for the path to an installed program (for some reason the PATH env variable was not correctly updated during the installation).

I do the following:

```
@ echo off
echo using %ppath%
where /q python2
if errorlevel 1 (
    set /p ppath= "Please enter the path to your python installation: "
    echo using %ppath%
)
```

For testing purpose I explicitly look for python2 which is not in the PATH of my machine
**My issue is that `echo using %ppath%` never prints what I just entered but the content of `%ppath%` from the previous execution of the batch file**. Here is a sample interactive usage:

```
C:\MyData\SoftDev\git\PDC_Python>fix_python_installation.bat
using install1
Please enter the path to your python installation: install2
using install1
C:\MyData\SoftDev\git\PDC_Python>fix_python_installation.bat
using install2
Please enter the path to your python installation:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I need unfortunately to stick to windows batch command for this task.

Comment: Neverending story about https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm new (hopefully for a very short time) to batch files.